# Chain rule: derivative vs integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, euler-maclaurin

What is the difference between the chain rule in a derivative versus the application of the chain rule in an integral? For example, in the case of derivative of $\ln(1+4x)$? I've done so many integrals, I believe I'm starting to mix methods when evaluating Maclaurin series.

Comment: The chain rule for integrals is what's usually called "u-substitution".

Comment: "Derivative of $\ln(1+4x)$" uses the usual chain rule (for derivatives). It might help if you gave an example of an integral in which there could be an "application of the chain rule," and show how you would apply it, so that we can understand clearly what you are concerned about.

Comment: i guess @Nick anwsered my question

Comment: I think you are confusing the concepts of chain rule in differentiation and change of variables formula in integration.

Comment: When do i use 'dx' in differentiating. I've used it in integrals so much I'm beginning to confused when I have to take a derivative.